# Calling onResume method after an alert is dismissed in Android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, onresume

I want to know if when the user presses "Yes" on an alert dialog and this one is dismissed, that event executes the onResume method of the activity in which the user is in.

Because I have a "Clean" button that asks the user if he's really sure of cleaning all the fields of the form (the activity) in order to redraw the activity with the empty fields.. The form is created dynamically, so I don't know a priori the elements in the GUI to set them empty...

Sorry for my bad english!!

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: if you want to detect when user did something you can use boolean that will be false on start and true on positive click of button?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not sure if this is the approach that should be taken, but you should be able to do what I think you are requesting.  If for some reason this is what you would want to achieve.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to clean?")
      .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
          dialog.dismiss();
          ((ActivityName) appContext).onResume();
        }
      })
      .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
          dialog.dismiss();
        }
      });
    builder.create().show();
}
```

You will really want to be calling your clean function **instead** of anything like a lifecycle call on a success while doing nothing on a failure.

Another potential way to approach this would be to bring the current activity back to the front using flags.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CurrentlyRunningActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Which would also provide a way to call upon your main activity without directly referencing the onResume() call, as pointed out is not the appropriate approach; however, I did want to directly respond to the question as it was asked.

Answer (score 1):

To see if a method is called you can put a breakpoint at the method, `onResume()`, to see what happens. If you aren't familiar with the Acitvity Lifecycle then doing this will help you familiarize yourself with it and reading the provided documentation.

Now, I don't think you should redraw your whole `layout` just to clear some `Views`. It would be more efficient, in my opinion, to just reset all fields by using `setText()` or another method for whatever you need when the user clicks "ok " or whatever. You can use [invalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) if you need to redraw certain `Views`

I also recommend watching

[Google I/O-Turbo Charge Your UI](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html)

[Activity LifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) <-- very important to understand

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK This is not possible since in order to have displayed the dialog box the activity would have already passed the onResume state. Check out the following page for more on the life cycle on an Android app (it really helped me understand better):

[App lifecycle](http://www.herongyang.com/Android/Activity-onCreate-and-Callback-Methods.html)

Comment: So, what you're saying is that when the alert is on screen, it doesn't cause the activity to be on background? it's still on foreground?

Comment: @alois.wirkes That's a good question that I am unsure of. However I think you should take a look at codeMagic's answer. You probably shouldn't redraw layouts to clear stuff, but should use the `setText()`. Just have the yes button of the dialog call a method that does the clean up you desire.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure when the onResume is called, add a log into the onResume method.